# Как получить список вопросов, которые получили правку после того, как были объявлены [требует-правки]?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, модерация

Каким образом можно посмотреть список вопросов, которые были исправлены после заморозки? На данный момент проверено [590 вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats), большая часть заморожена. Как понять какие стоит уже переоткрыть (ну а вдруг?)?

По вопросам/ответам плохого качества аналогичная проблема. Если автор сообщения внес изменения, то комментарии и минусы за ответ/вопрос так и будут висеть, потому что проверяющий уже высказался и чтобы изменить мнение нужно просматривать [всю историю](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/history)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вручную искать вопросы для переоткрытия обычно не требуется.

Если замороженный вопрос редактируется, то он автоматически попадает в очередь на переоткрытие. Соответственно, ловить его нужно там. Если вопроса там нет, то, значит, остальные участники уже оценили, нужно ли вопрос переоткрывать.

Когда вопрос из замороженного становится закрытым, он больше не попадает в очередь на переоткрытие, и для того, чтобы вопрос переоткрыть, надо будет или обратиться к ромбовому модератору с помощью тревоги, или написать на Мете.

Возможности отследить за редактированием замороженных вопросов, чтобы исправить свою оценку, к сожалению, нет. На MSE было похожее предложение: [Уведомления об исправлении для проминусовавших пост](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1751/allow-an-edit-to-notify-downvoters-i-think-ive-fixed-the-issue-now-please-c). К сожалению, оно было отклонено.

В комментариях к тому посту предложили "воркэраунд": оставить под проминусованным постом свой комментарий, в котором вы объясняете недостатки. Тогда, если после редактирования поста автор уведомит вас в комментарии с помощью прямого обращения `@user`, то вы получите уведомление. Тут правда есть нюанс, что это долго, неудобно, ненадёжно, может иметь неприятные последствия и т.п. Но в некоторых случаях подобный подход работает, проверено.

Comment: Да, нашел в справке http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions внизу. С закрытыми понятно и хорошо. / По поводу минусов - очень жаль. Этот как раз к теме о уважении участников, в частности новичков. Если давать комментарий или ставить минус, значит надеяться на какую-то реакцию. Понятно, что адекватная реакция довольно редка, но если реакции не ожидать вовсе, то выглядит это крайне невоспитанно. Вероятно, для меня может оказаться проще, если ревью для таких вопросов/ответов не делать вовсе - пропускать, зато возможного негатива буду меньше генерить.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Если заминусовать плохой вопрос, то негатив будет в адрес одного пользователя — автора. Если оставить плохой вопрос, то на него наткнутся сотни других посетителей, и в сумме негатива будет больше.

Comment: Все верно, но это будет не моя проблема. Люди с пониженным чувством вины справятся без меня :)

Comment: Разве закрытые не попадают в очередь на переоткрытие?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Только замороженные, для переоткрытия закрытого нужно обращаться на мету или к модератору.